# Separate binary logs for each database in MySQL

Tags: backup, mysql

I have been working with Sybase databases for few years. In Sybase databases you have separate binary log for each database. Backup and restore operation with binary logs for single database is not complicated, relatively safe (no risk of messing up another databases) etc.

Now I'm trying to set up incremental backups for MySQL (MariaDB to be more precise) and I have found, that there are binary logs for whole server (all databases have common binary log).

Does it mean that if I want to use separate binary logs for each database I have to create multiple MySQL server instances?

Comment: You could have the common `binlog` but extract only the content relevant to a `DB` of interest. Use `mysqlbinlog --database DB` which you can then pipe or redirect to backup location. You can that separate backup for each DB.

Comment: While going in that Direction , you might want to also use `--raw` & `--result-file` to customize your backup Process.

Comment: @Prem Thanks. I have just tried mysqlbinlog --database "mydatabase". It makes a warning about GDID's, I have to read about that. Unfortunately `--raw` parameter cannot be used with `--database`, so I have to use SQL output files and use some CPU time to compress them.

Comment: Only to test whether this method is satisfactory or not , you might try `--skip-gtids` & proceed.